# Image searching system using Bag Of Features method

Tags: computer-vision

I am doing a project making visual search system using Bag Of Features method but have little question. If I understood the method correctly, the method has few steps.

1. Feature extraction from an image
2. Vector quantization
3. Image searching from a database

I am stock at between 2 and 3. I use python package called scikit-learn to quantize the feature vectors extracted using SIFT algorithm in opencv. For now, I set the cluster size 8 with default setting. I tried to generate histogram out of the output codebook and display it. I tried this with same image several times but all the histograms looked different. The code is below. It is a simple code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def feature_extract(img):
    sift = cv2.SIFT()
    gray = img
    kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
    return kp, des


def codebook(k, des):
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=k, max_iter=500)
    km.fit(des)
    codebook = km.cluster_centers_
    label = km.labels_
    return codebook, label

img = cv2.imread('sift_example.jpg', 0)
kp, des = feature_extract(img)

k = 8
codebook, label = codebook(k, des)
plt.hist(label, bins=range(0,9), align='left'), plt.show()
```

I suspect that the problem come from the clustering error. Since the initial centers for clustering is set to random, the final converged centers are different. 
Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the randomness of KMeans initial centers, but I would assume that if you dont explicitely change the initial seed of the random number generator, then it would always pick the same "random" features as initial centers.
Another reason could be that, if feature detection/extraction is multithreaded, the features computed on your image can appear in different orders between each run. You might check that aswell.

Alternatively, you can pass your own centers to KMeans as initial centroids so you could pick them or generate them by yourself to make sure KMeans starts with always the same initial centers

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem comes from choosing the initial centroids randomly so that the centroids converges to different final centroids. I thought about fixing the initial centroids so that it always converges to the same final centroids. So there is no way to find global minimum centroids in clustering??

Comment: No garanty with KMeans, but using kmeans++ initialisation gives you more chance to get to the global minimum.